# Why doesn't my get method getAuthor() return output?

Tags: java, return

My BookTester class is creating a new book and calling getAuthor(), but when I run, it doesn't return any output. I'm not sure why? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
public class BookTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book myBook = new Book("My life", "Sam Daily", 2001);
        myBook.getAuthor();
    } 
}

class Book {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int publishedYear;

    public Book(String title, String author, int year)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        publishedYear = year; 
    }

    public int getYear(){
        System.out.println(publishedYear);
        return publishedYear;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor(){
        return author; 
    }
}
```

Comment: you're ignoring the result from the method call.

Comment: You don't do anything with the return value...

Comment: `System.out.println(myBook.getAuthor());`

Comment: How do you know it doesn't return output? If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?

Comment: @BoristheSpider good shout! loving the theory there :).

Answer (score 1):

The method signature:

```
public String getAuthor(){ ... }
```

represents a method that takes no parameters and *returns a `String`*. even the name of the method speaks it "getAuthor", to get or retrieve something.

and you're ignoring the result of the method call.

the solution is either store the result to a variable and then operate on it.

```
String author = myBook.getAuthor();
```

or if you want to print to the console then you can do:

```
System.out.println(myBook.getAuthor());
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason why you don't see returned value is because you are ignoring it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Book myBook = new Book("My life", "Sam Daily", 2001);
    myBook.getAuthor(); // Value is returned but not used
}
```

Instead you could assign returned value to variable and print it or just print it from method call:

`System.out.println(myBook.getAuthor());`

Considering that this is really basic thing I suggest you to get some good Java book or some tutorial in other to advance faster.

Answer (score 0):

The method `getAuthor()` effectivly returns something, but you did not use it

1. You can store it to use after :

   ```
   String author = myBook.getAuthor();
   System.out.println(author);          // for simple printing
   System.out.println(author.charAt(1));          // to print a single char
   ...
   ```
2. You can print it directly

   ```
   System.out.println("The author is "+ myBook.getAuthor());
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First receive method result in string variable  and print it..

string result=myBook.getAuthor();

system.out.println(result);